# PDF to Editable Documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pdf, electron

I just want to ask if there is any resource which can do PDF to Editable Document conversion like in Word, Excel or powerpoint. Let me know if it is possible. My preferred architecture is NodeJS or Javascript. I have done following research:

1. Reading the .pdf in binary and extracting all information then creating the document according to that but it is a very long term solution.
2. I want to do the conversion in editable way so i don't want to do it using images mapping.

Do share if there is any paid resource available, and it must not be an API because i need to give offline support.

Regards
Ali Muqaddas

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unoconf` (https://github.com/gfloyd/node-unoconv) for that.

Example from the library README:

```
unoconv.convert('document.docx', 'pdf', function (err, result) {
    // result is returned as a Buffer
    fs.writeFile('converted.pdf', result);
});
```

Comment: Come on man, i am asking for PDF => Word. Not for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a clear solution for this.

I have also been looking for the same thing. I have found these 2 APIs that allow for this, but I'm looking for something offline too.

Nonetheless, these APIs might be useful for you or maybe they are exactly what you have been looking for.

- [PDFTron](https://www.pdftron.com/) - Limited documentation and kinda unclear. I tried to work with this a couple of times but never managed to get it working, but if you can seeing from their demo, the results look really nice.
- [ASPOSE](https://products.aspose.cloud/words/nodejs/) - Offers a free tier demo license, however, the conversion is a bit...weird. Meaning no images just text, therefore, the padding and margin are way off.

Doing the opposite is easy and FREE! (DOCX -> PDF), however, (PDF -> DOCX) seems to be (1) Expensive and (2) Impossible to implement offline.